# Saving file to disk while running AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and CMMotionManager

Tags: iphone, avcapturesession

Good day, hope someone can help me up with this situation:

I working on an iPhone app that takes series of images, assisted by gyroscope.
So both AVCamCaptureManager and CMMotionManager sessions are running at the same time.

after taking a still image, i am:
- processing the image in a background thread (which works fine without affecting anything)
- then saving processed image data to disk

```
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

The issue: both AVCamCaptureManager and CMMotionManager sessions freeze for less then 1/2 second, right after initiating writeToFile function.

Does anyone have any experience with such scenario?
Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: It appears that saving to disk does not affect sessions.

I am also setting UIImageView.image to a large image in the end of my routine, and this is what was freezing everything for 1/2 second.

Cropping and compressing the large image to UIImageView.size did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that saving to disk does not affect sessions.

I am also setting UIImageView.image to a large image in the end of my routine, and this is what was freezing everything for 1/2 second.